# Create multiple text files from excel cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have the text I want to use as the file name in Column B, and the content I want to add in to these files in adajacent cells in Column C. The solution is probably pretty simple, but the code I have now is creating the text files with the right name without actually writing anything to the file.

I have little to no VBA experience so this code is 100% based off of something I found on this forum

```
Sub CreateFiles()

    Dim sExportFolder, sFN
    Dim rName As Range
    Dim action As Range
    Dim oSH As Worksheet
    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim oTxt As Object

    'sExportFolder = path to the folder you want to export to
    'oSh = The sheet where your data is stored

    sExportFolder = "H:\"
    Set oSH = Sheet1

    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

    For Each rName In oSH.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
        Set action = rName.Offset(, 1)


        'Add .txt to the article name as a file name

        sFN = rName.Value & ".txt"
        Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & "\" & sFN, 2, True)
        oTxt.WriteLine action.Value
        oTxt.Close
    Next
```

Comment: Try stepping through your code line by line to see if `action.Value` is what you expect. You can do that by selecting your `oTxt.WriteLine action.Value` line, then going to the Debug menu and clicking Run To Cursor

Comment: You already have a backslash on the end of `sExportFolder` so don't add another one when you create the file...

Comment: There are some minor discrepancies in your question compared to your code. In itself, the code works, but it is reading from column A and B, rather than B and C. `Sheet1` is also a something that is not what you might want. Try `Set oSH = Worksheets(1)` instead

Comment: `file name in Column B`, yet you are using `A` for file names and if you say you are getting the right names, then well... they are in column `A`.  Also, `the content ......  in Column C`, but you are using `B`. This `Set action = rName.Offset(, 1)` it means `1 Column to the right from the first column in your range rName (which is A)`. If you do have the content in `C`, and still want to use `A` for file names, you should use `Set action = rName.Offset(, 2)` (2 columns to the right...).

Answer (score 1):

To add to my comment, here is how your code should look, if you are looking in column **B** for file names, and column **C** for values:

Please set your sheet name in the code

```vb
Sub CreateFiles()

    Dim sExportFolder As String, sFN As String
    Dim oSH As Worksheet
    Dim rName As Range
    Dim oFS As Object, oTxt As Object

    sExportFolder = "H:\"
    Set oSH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Your Sheet Name Here") '<-- set sheet name here
    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

    For Each rName In oSH.Range("B1:B" & oSH.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
        If rName.Value <> "" Then
            sFN = rName.Value & ".txt"
            Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & sFN, 2, True)
            oTxt.WriteLine rName.Offset(0, 1)
            oTxt.Close
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! So I just copied and pasted your code and a few things happened. I get a "path not found" error, even though the path exists. Only four text files are created, and they have the Column C text as the title instead of Column B. I changed the path twice and the same thing happened.

Comment: @guppy you have file names in B or A? This looks for file names in B.

Comment: File names are in B and file content is in C. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @guppy then it should work... hm... see updated code in a second, there is a backslash there adding twice.

Comment: `oSH.UsedRange.Columns("A")` is a relative reference, to the first column of the UsedRange.  _If_ column A is entirely empty that will be Column B

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks for pointing that out, I don't use usedrange that often and wasn't aware of it. I've updated the answer with a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CreateFiles()

    Dim sExportFolder, sFN
    Dim rName As Range
    Dim action As Range
    Dim oSH As Worksheet
    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim oTxt As Object

    'sExportFolder = path to the folder you want to export to
    'oSh = The sheet where your data is stored

    sExportFolder = "H:\"
    Set oSH = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

    For Each rName In oSH.UsedRange.Columns("B").Cells
        Set action = rName.Offset(, 1)


        'Add .txt to the article name as a file name

        sFN = rName.Value & ".txt"
        Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & "\" & sFN, 2, True)
        oTxt.WriteLine action.Value
        oTxt.Close
    Next
```